# I'm lost in the shader editor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine, procedural

[image]Everytime I hold scroll on my mouse to move, it like somehow teleports down and I have to scroll up again. THis time, it was WAY WORSE, as it went too far down and now I can't find my nodes

Comment: If you scroll your mouse wheel until you're zoomed all the way out, two primary X&Y grid lines will become much more apparent (although if you're _way_ out it's possible that neither will be visible). If this is the case, pan until you find one of them and then follow it to the other - your nodes should be at or near their intersection.

Comment: this problem is legit annoying though, sometimes I wanna tool around on the laptop and this problem is an absolute nightmare on a touchpad

Answer (score 9):

You can use the <kbd>Home</kbd> button or press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all of your nodes and then use <kbd>Numpad .</kbd> to frame selected.

[image]

Comment: ... and the short-short-cut for that, in all editors, is the `Home` key, if you've got one.

Comment: And if you don't have a Home key, just go *View > Frame All* :)