# understanding Shading vs Material properties

Tags: shaders

I am quite new here and struggling to figure out why there are two places to control shading, and how to switch which one actually controls the shading. Also: what is the semantic difference between "material properties" and "shading" from blender's point of view?

1. `Layout tab > Properties > Material Properties > Material > Surface > Use nodes`
   this one works, but here I am able to use a single node only

[image]

2. `Shading tab > Shader editor > Object`
   I see a number of cool tutorials on how to use this one with multiple nodes. However, changing things here has no effect on the object shading. I clearly see that it refers to the object of interest "backsplash", still no effect.

[image]

Comment: Yeah something isn't right, there.  The material output node should have a maroon colored header if it's the active output.

Comment: Frame all nodes with the Home button and see if there aren't some extra nodes hanging around.

Comment: @AllenSimpson how do I "frame all nodes with the Home button" -- are you talking about the Shader view? Where do I find "Home button"?

Comment: Clicking on the header of the "Output" node in the Shader view made the header maroon, and now it seems to control the shading. Strange...

Comment: On the keyboard :p - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/210908/im-lost-in-the-shader-editor/210909#210909

Comment: It must be that a second Material Output got added, whichever was last selected will be active.  You can delete one of them.

Comment: I am on Mac, there is no Home key

Comment: I see, sorry.  It was my assumption.  You can still use the menus in the answer I linked.

Comment: In the node editor header, View > Frame All

Answer (score 1):

If both images are the same material:

1. You should see only one node.  The Material Output Node doesn't show up.  If you want to add other nodes, you need to click on the circle in the *Principled* node that represents the input you want to connect and select from the popup.  Here's an example of clicking on *Base Color*'s Yellow node:

[image: Clicking on the Base Color node]

If I were to, say, select *Brick Texture*, then the Base Color input would change to

[image: Base color showing Brick settings]

and all of the Brick Texture settings would become available.  I could click on the ↓ (down arrow) to "close" the Brick Texture panel.

You can edit everything this way but it becomes very difficult to follow.

2. Your problem is that you have the 3D viewport in *Solid* Viewport Shading mode. That doesn't show your material.  There are two Viewport Shading modes that do.  See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/248036/42221) for a detailed explanation.